# What are the recommended specs for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hardware

I tried starting up a new world of Minecraft today, and found much to my displeasure that something as simple as breaking a tree, on a single-player world, would run into glitchy, laggy, unplayable problems.

My computer is...rather old.  It has a AMD Athlon II 620 Quad-Core processor, a Nvidia 9100 integrated graphics card, 4 G of Ram, 640 GB hard drive, and it runs Windows 7.  I literally updated java just yesterday, so...what am I missing to make Minecraft run properly?

Comment: Integrated graphics is the problem. Minecraft is more graphically demanding than many AAA titles, despite appearances.

Comment: SevenSidedDie is right, go to the graphics settings in minecraft and set them all to the lowest demanding option eg set render distance to "tiny"

Comment: also install the optifine mod

Comment: optifine may not work, it really depends on the hardware and settings with whether it will help or hinder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oddly, Mojang doesn't have any minimum or recommended specs on minecraft.net, instead burying it in a crowd-sourced [help article about system requirements](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-system-requirements).

You appear to have more than the minimum required specs:

> Minimum Requirements:
>   CPU : Intel P4 or its AMD Equivalent (AMD K7)
>   RAM : 2GB
>   GPU : Intel GMA 950 or AMD Equivalent with OpenGL 2.1 Support
>   HDD : At least 100MB for Game Core and Sound Files

… but your system falls far short of the recommended specs due to not having a discrete graphics card:

> Recommended Requirements:
>   CPU : Intel Pentium D or AMD Athlon 64 (K8) 2.6 GHz
>   RAM : 4GB
>   GPU : GeForce 6xxx or ATI Radeon 9xxx and up with OpenGL 2.1 Support (Excluding Integrated Chipsets)
>   HDD : 150MB

Comment: Thanks.  I think clearly though I'll have to aim a slightly bit higher than this for the more recent AAA games.  I do intend to eventually play the new X-Com on this after all.